# Lemniscate of Bernoulli in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, math

I found a very interesting thread in the GameDev side, link below:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/43704

I would like to implement this formula to draw a eight/infinity sign into in view, I don't see how I can do this. 
Someone can give a clue to start the code?

Thanks for reading,

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Translating the parametric representation to a Cartesian representation? Creating a view on which you can draw your own graphics? We don't know what to tell you if you aren't specific.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Yes, It is the translation of parametric representation to a Cartesian rep. Creating a view is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the parametric representation

```
scale = 2 / (3 - cos(2*t));
x = scale * cos(t);
y = scale * sin(2*t) / 2;
```

it's quite straightforward to write the code that draws the figure. What you do is start the variable `t` at 0, and increment it in a loop by a small value (say 0.05) each iteration until it reaches `2*PI`. At each step, draw a line from the previous (x, y) point to the next calculated point. This will be a short line for each step, but together they will form the curved figure.

You can fiddle with the increment value to generate a figure that looks good for your application.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that was my missing part!